# Why can't root execute when executable bits are not set?

Tags: bash, permissions, root, executable

`root` user *can* write to a file even if its `write` permissions are not set.

`root` user *can* read a file even if its `read` permissions are not set.

`root` user *can* `cd` into a directory even if its `execute` permissions are not set.

`root` user *cannot* execute a file when its `execute` permissions are not set.

Why?

```
user$ echo '#!'$(which bash) > file
user$ chmod 000 file
user$ ls -l file
---------- 1 user user 12 Jul 17 11:11 file
user$ cat file                      # Normal user cannot read
cat: file: Permission denied
user$ su
root$ echo 'echo hello' >> file     # root can write
root$ cat file                      # root can read
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
root$ ./file                        # root cannot execute
bash: ./file: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In short, because the execute bit is considered special; if it's not set *at all*, then the file is considered to be not an executable and thus can't be executed.

However, if even ONE of the execute bits is set, root can and will execute it.

Observe:

```
caleburn: ~/ >cat hello.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello!"

caleburn: ~/ >chmod 000 hello.sh
caleburn: ~/ >./hello.sh
-bash: ./hello.sh: Permission denied
caleburn: ~/ >sudo ./hello.sh 
sudo: ./hello.sh: command not found

caleburn: ~/ >chmod 100 hello.sh
caleburn: ~/ >./hello.sh
/bin/sh: ./hello.sh: Permission denied
caleburn: ~/ >sudo ./hello.sh 
Hello!
```

Comment: Where are special cases defined? Is this part of e.g. a POSIX spec? Are the `root` special rules specific to Linux, or do all Unixes follow the same approach here?

Comment: @nh2 I must have explained it poorly because your question doesn't make sense. This isn't about a "special case"; it just works out that way because of the way the executable bit is regarded. This isn't a "special rule" for root or anyone else. It refuses to execute the file because without any exec bit set, *it is not considered to be an executable*. It doesn't matter that you have the master key that opens all locks because *that isn't a door*.

Comment: I understood your answer (I first thought that it was special for root, because you wrote "if ... one of the execute bits is set, root can execute it", which made it sound like it is specific to root, but your following examples disambiguated that). With the "special rules" I was referring to the points in the original question that allow root to read/write/cd even though the appropriate permissions are not set. I am wondering whether that (and the concept of the super-user in general) is a standardised concept, or an OS-specific implementation detail. Further ...

Comment: ... Further I would also like to know whether the concept of "one `x` bit makes it generally executable" is a general Unix/POSIX rule, or an OS implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days system administration tools lived in `/etc` such as `/etc/restore`, `/etc/rrestore`, `/etc/init`, `/etc/halt`, etc. Imagine what would happen if `root`'s `PATH` was set to `/etc:/bin` and `root` ran `passwd`.

It wouldn't work right.

To make matters worse, in the old days, binary executables didn't have magic headers, so checking if the binary was an executable wasn't really possible except by checking permission bits. So they made files not valid targets of `exec`* unless they were actually files (no directories, etc.) and had at least one execute bit set.

*The check might have been in execvp, which is a user-mode function.

It's still a useful check as in theory anything could be a shell script, so why take it out?